# using the onKeyDown event inside wtform

Tags: python, flask

currently trying to use flask and wtforms to make an html form.
My for template looks like this:

```
<ul><li>Description:</li>
<li> <textarea class="input" rows="10" cols="50" name="description" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.description,this.form.countdown,150);"
```

onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.description,this.form.countdown,150);">
    description of the article.You have  characters left.

I wanted to use wtforms and just replace:

```
<textarea..> with {{form.description}}.
```

But then how do I incorporate the onkeydown event ? I need that to count the number of characters typed already in the textarea.

BTW. My form which I made using wtforms  looks like this:

```
class ItemForm(Form):
title       = TextField("Title")
subtitle    = TextAreaField("Sub Title")
Description = TextAreaField("Description")
offervalue  = FloatField("Offer Value")
imagefile_1 = FileField("Image File 1")
imagefile_2 = FileField("Image File 2")
imagefile_3 = FileField("Image File 3")
```

QUESTION: HOW SHOULD I STILL INCLUDE THE JAVASCRIPT TO ANY EVEN THAT HAPPENS IN THE TEXTAREA?

thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something to select the textarea and bind the keyboard events to it. I'd suggest jQuery like so:

```js
$('textarea .input').keypress(function() {
  limitText(this.form.description,this.form.countdown,150);
});
```

You can see the documentation for the `keypress` event here: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ jQuery also can bind to `keyup` or `keydown` events.

If you aren't familiar with jQuery, this is a good place to start: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'm a bit late, but my personal receipe is:

1. Keep your scripts in separate file, i.e. `myscripts.js`
2. Attach `myscripts.js` to required HTML page via `<script
   url="<path/to/myscripts.js>"></scripts>`
3. Suppose you have function `foo(eventObject)` in `myscripts.js`, and element `bar` in target HTML-page.
4. Put into `myscripts.js` function `linker()`, that will glue these components (I use jQuery for this as example, but fill free to use plain JavaScript as well):

   function linker() {
     $(bar).on(*event*, function blablabla(eventObject) { foo(eventObject); })
   }
5. Call `linker()` from your HTML page.